# How to make pictures from database clickable with different HTML?

Tags: php

i have this code:

```
<div class="row mt-2">
        <?php
        include 'config.php';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="card p-2 border-secondary mb-2">
                        <a href="link'.$row['zdjecie_produktu']/'"><img style="margin-left:30px;" src="<?= $row['zdjecie_produktu'] ?>" class="card-img-top" height="250"></a>
                        <div style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;" class="card-body p-1">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center text-info"><?= $row['nazwa_produktu'] ?> </h4>
                            <h5 style="color:#fff;" class="card-text text-center text-danger"><?= number_format($row['cena_produktu'],2) ?>zł</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer p-1">
                            <form action="" class="form-submit">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?= $row['nazwa_produktu'] ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?= $row['cena_produktu'] ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pimage" value="<?= $row['zdjecie_produktu'] ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="<?= $row['kod_produktu'] ?>">
                                <button style="margin-left:300px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block addItemBtn"><img src="cart.png" width="20px;"></button>
                                <style>
      .btn:hover {
        background: #F5E595;
      }
    </style>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
 </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

 </div>
</div>
```

But i  want each picture to be linked with different HTML (in this case with picture of the product with its’ description)... is there any code for that?

Comment: So, you're asking if there is a way to dynamically change `href`?

Comment: simply use different target in your [a tag] e.g. <a href=product.php?serial=1234>

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes i think so

Comment: Then build `href` the way you build `src` of your `img` tag - based on a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The key ingredient is to have a **Unique ID** as reference.
If you have a products Array data (from database or wherever) say like:

```php
// products.php 

// $products Array // Multiple products from database
$products = [
  [
    "id" => 101,
    "img" => "101.jpg",
    "name" => "foo",
    "desc" => "bar",
    "price" => 123.45,
  ],
  // [ ...another one here
];
```

Than all you need is to iterate them:

```php
// products.php 

foreach ($products as $pr):
   echo "<a href=\"product.php?id={$pr['id']}\"><img src=\"products/{$pr['img']}\" alt=\"{$pr['desc']}\"> {$pr['name']} - {$pr['price']}$</a>";
endforeach;
```

Notice above the Search Query Param `product.php?id=101` - get it's value inside `product.php` page from the HTTP Request by using [GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).
Than all you need is to query the database for that single product by its ID:

```php
// product.php

$productId = $_GET['id']; // @TODO: check if isset and validate
echo $productId; // 101

// Go query database, get single product by ID and display it
// Don't forget to use PDO Prepared Statements when querying the DB
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: i get this on my page: 
foreach ($product as $pr): echo " {$pr['nazwa_produktu']} - {$pr['cena_produktu']}$"; endforeach;... instead of pictures

Comment: @OmegaMarcinek that's most probably because you don't use a PHP file (likely a `.html`?). Please see again the provided sample code, and make sure you're in a PHP environment.

Comment: no.. i am using php file... i dont know whats wrong

Comment: @OmegaMarcinek see this example: https://phpsandbox.io/n/blue-frost-0xlb

Comment: i g et this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MyoNm3NSuPftxHiqS77UO6lOEbHED2Nx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @OmegaMarcinek where can I see the actual code? That image cannot help much

Comment: i pasted it in the question

Answer (score -1):

Basically, all you have to do is to create a php file, called product.php and supply it with GET parameter or query string.

The steps would be something like this:

1. create a php file: `product.php`
2. inside, you would select your product detail and display it:

   ```
   $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''

   if($id == '') { die('Invalid product id.'); }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = :id";
   //process this query using your database method of choices

   //if product found, display the detail HTML:

   <div class="product-name"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></div>
   <img src="<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>"><br>
   ```
3. Now back to your product list, change its `<a>`'s `href` to `product.php?id=$id`

   ```
     <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>">
      <img style="margin-left:30px;" src="<?= $row['zdjecie_produktu'] ?>" class="card-img-top" height="250">
     </a>
   ```